# React Router dynamic routing based on JS Array

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm making a simple marketplace, that has a home page with product cards - the cards are generated from an internal JS file (**Data.js**). It goes like this because I need to generate random names, and I use a function for that. The array goes like this:

```
let Data= [{
id: i,
nomeCompleto: nomeCompleto,
valor: preco(),
isFavorite: false,]}
```

When I click on the card, I use a dynamic route:

```
 <Route path ='produto/:id' element={productSpecs}/>
```

It is working fine, the `xxx/produto/id` always matches the product `id`. The problem is, it's returning all of the array from `Data`. I need it to return only `Data[(id - 2])`.
As it is now, `productSpecs` is defined on the **App.js** as below, replacing props on `ProductInfo`:

```
const productSpecs = Data.map(item => {
  return (
    <ProductInfo 
      key = {item.id}
      id = {item.id}
      img = {item.img} 
      nomeCompleto = {item.nomeCompleto}
      valor = {item.valor}
      favorite = {item.isFavorite}
      />
  )
})
```

Should I define the props on the Product Info JSX? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Following your question, you could retrieve the `id` param inside of the `ProductInfo` and do a `find()` on the `Data` to get the product you're trying to display.

```
function ProductInfo() {
  const { id } = useParams()
  const product = Data.find(product => product.id === id);
  
  ...
}
```

and on the Routing level you could have

```
<Route path ='product/:id' element={<ProductInfo />}/>
```

Comment: It worked! I didn't need to use the const product, just the id on useParams was enough. Used {Data[id - 2].value} and it was enough haha